# Compact Kähler manifolds with $dim_\mathbb{C}H^{1,1}(X)=1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In Wells's book 《differential analysis on complex manifolds》 page219, there is a statement:" any compact Kähler manifold $X$ with the property that  dim$_\mathbb{C}H^{1,1}(X)=1$ is necessarily Hodge. This follow from the fact that multiplication by an appropriate constant will make the Kähler form on $X$ integral."
But I know by Kodaira's Embedding theorem, a compact Kähler manifold is projective if and only if the Kähler class $[\omega]\in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, I don't see dim$_\mathbb{C}H^{1,1}(X)=1$ imply $[\omega]\in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, the reason is that $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ can be seen as integral lattice in the vector space $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$, and 1-dimensional $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb{C})$ can be seen as a 1-dimensional sub vector space of $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$, the intersection of $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb{C})$ may probably be empty? so that the compact Kähler manifold $X$ with dim$_\mathbb{C}H^{1,1}(X)=1$ is not necessarily Hodge? Is that right?

Comment: May probably be empty? No. Think about real cohomology.

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin, for example let $H^2(X,\mathbb{R})$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ may be the integral lattice in it, let $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb{R})$ be $\mathbb R$, it's a line, if take unrational slope, the line will intersect no integral point in the $H^2(X,\mathbb{R})$, isn't it?

Comment: In a false attempt to answer this question, as pointed it out by Tom and Ted, I realized that the intersection of $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb C)$ and $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ may only contain $\{0\}$, and this is true for a general weight two Hodge structure. Although we couldn't found a counterexample so far (since standard examples non-algebraic Kahler varieties have $h^{1,1}>1$), I believe the reasoning in the book is false. Namely, the argument on scaling is incorrect if there is no additional assumption.

Comment: @AG learner, what a  pity that you delete your previous answer. Although there may be something wrong with your answer, actually I cann't figure out where it goes wrong, in fact I was almost persuaded by your answer, it seems quite reasonable, when I was trying to understand it, you deleted it. And the comments by Ted following your answer is also very valuable, so I think if you did not delete your answer but add some explanations why it's wrong, it will be more helpful to the audience and be a perfect answer.

Comment: @Tom: Sorry, I thought a wrong answer may mislead others...Now I have recovered it. Maybe I'll edit that later.

Comment: @AG learner, it won't mislead others if there is a explanation in the second part of  your answer, and I think it will be more helpful to exhibit the unsucessful tries, it is more close to our process of thinking, even better than only give the "right answer". and I think I still learn something valuable from the unsuccessful try. Thank for your recovery:)

Comment: Let me add a final comment. Irrespective of the value of $h^{1,1}$, if $h^{2,0}=0$, then the result is of course true.

Comment: We might be able to construct an example if we can find a complex $2$-torus that has no subvarieties and admits an automorphism of order $4$. The quotient of it by the automorphism would hopefully be a compact Kahler manifold with $h^{1,1} = 1$, but it would not be projective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, **now I think the argument in the book is incorrect, at least with the given assumption. The following was my first attempt to answer this question, where the crossed sentences are insufficient**:

> Every compact Kahler manifold $X$ admits a Kahler form $[\omega]\in  H^2(X,\mathbb C)$ which is nonzero. Moreover, $[\omega]$ is real and of type $(1,1)$. Therefore, by the assumption that $\dim_{\mathbb C}H^{1,1}(X)=1$, $[\omega]$ is a real element of the complex vector space $\mathbb C\cong H^{1,1}(X)$. One can rescale $[\omega]$ by a constant $r\in\mathbb R^+$, such that $r[\omega]\in H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ <s>is integral</s> and still stay in the Kahler cone.

> For your confusion, you can check from the fact $H^{1,1}(X)$ is a complex subspace of $H^{2}(X,\mathbb C)$ such that $\overline{H^{1,1}(X)}=H^{1,1}(X)$, it follows that $$H^{1,1}(X)= \big (H^{1,1}(X)\bigcap H^2(X,\mathbb R)\big )\otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C.$$
> <s>So in particular, the intersection $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\cap H^{1,1}(X)\neq \{0\}}$</s>.

The reason of insufficiency is the following: Since $H^{1,1}(X)$ is 1-dimensional, the Kahler cone is a ray $\mathbb R^+$ in the real vector space $H^2(X,\mathbb R)$, so $X$ is a Hodge manifold iff the that ray passes an (nonzero) integral element in $H^2(X,\mathbb R)$. Explicitly, let's say $h^{2,0}=h^{0,2}=1$, and $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is a basis of $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$, then $[\omega]=\sum_{i=1}^3r_iv_i$ for some $r_i\in \mathbb R$, can we gurantee that $[r_1:r_2:r_3]=[n_1:n_2:n_3]$ with $n_i$ integer? No, and general weight two Hodge structure won't satisfy that.

Comment: Consider 1-dimensional $H^{1,1}(X)$ as a 2-dimensional $\mathbb R^2$ plane, suppose it is determined by the equation $y=\sqrt2 x$ in higher dimensional space, for visual reasons $\mathbb R^3$, then any rescale cannot bring the point representing Kähler class  to the integral lattice for the plane cannot intersect any integral points, isn't it?

Comment: @AGlearner: I think I'm now on Tom's side. If $h^{0,2} = h^{2,0} > 0$, then I think he's correct that the $1$-dimensional (real) $H^{1,1}(X)$ can sit very irrationally inside $H^2(X,\Bbb Z)\otimes\Bbb C$, which has complex dimension at least $3$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Now I see the issue. I used to think $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb Z)$ as contained in $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$, but it is not true.

Comment: @TedShifrin Presumably there should be a counterexample, and since $Pic(X)=H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb Z)$, such counterexample $X$ should admit no divisor at all. I don't think I know such an example with $h^{1,1}=1$. Do you have any?

Comment: I definitely do *not* have examples. :(

Comment: It helps a lot, thanks!